# Cannot assign to property: 'card' is a 'let' constant in a for loop in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, for-loop

Cannot assign to property: 'card' is a 'let' constant in for loop in chooseCard method. I am not able to figure out why the error is coming in the for loop .what am I missing in the code .Please help.

```
import Foundation

class Concentration {

    var cards = [Card]()

    var faceUpCount = 0

    func chooseCard(atIndex : Int) {
        var alreadyFaceUpCard  = Card()
        if faceUpCount == 0 {
            alreadyFaceUpCard = cards[atIndex]
            alreadyFaceUpCard.isFaceUp = true
            faceUpCount += 1
        }else if faceUpCount == 1 {
            var card = cards[atIndex]
            card.isFaceUp = true
            if alreadyFaceUpCard.identifier == card.identifier {
                alreadyFaceUpCard.isMatchUp = true
                card.isMatchUp = true
                faceUpCount += 1
            }

        }else {
            for card in cards {
                card.isFaceUp = false
            }

        }

    }



    init(numberOfPairsOfCards : Int) {
        for _ in 1...numberOfPairsOfCards {
            let card = Card()
            cards.append(card)
            cards.append(card)
        }
        // TODO: Shuffle Cards
    }


}
```

Comment: Is `Card` a struct?

Comment: I can make assumption that Card is struct ?

Comment: yes Card is Struct

Comment: card is ofcourse a let constant, to make it variable use:  ` for var card in cards`

Comment: @sriramhegde, you shouldn't use `struct` if you want to have shared modifiable state, think about changing it to `class` instead.

Comment: If it is a protocol, make sure it conforms to AnyObject

Answer (score 34, accepted):

card is ofcourse a let constant, to make it variable use:  `for var card in cards`

Comment: That makes it compile, but  it does not work as expected.  `card.isFaceUp = false` inside the loop modifies only the local loop variable, not the array elements.

Comment: Thus, you can use:
    for (index, _) in cards.enumerated() {
cards(index).isFaceUp = false
}

Comment: @MartinR did u find suitable workaround?

Comment: the "Card" is Struct,So when U seting a value  to Struct wil copy all value,not pointer. so in closure,  "card" i s a  totally new vaue.

Comment: solution1: change Card struct to class ;or solution2: get index of value ,example `for i in 0..<cards.count {cards[i].isFaceUp = false}`

Comment: This code can modify the original cards array ```for (idx, card) in cards.enumerated() { card[idx].isFaceUp = false }```